# AVD not creating config.ini file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have windows 8.1 64bit, android studio updated to v1.0 RC. everything used to work properly before I updated to the rc version.

1. I open Android Studio
2. I launch AVD Manager
3. I create Virtual Device (Nexus_6_API_21)
4. it create it, but AVD Manager doesn't give me an option to run it, but it gives "failed to load" in the action column.
5. I used a command line to run it: `emulator.exe -avd Nexus_6_API_21`, and it says:

   `PANIC: Could not open AVD config file: F:\Programming\sdk\.android\avd\Nexus_6_API_21.avd\config.ini`
6. I browse that folder to find only userdata.img file and there is no config.ini
7. I copied the Nexus_6_API_21.ini which is available in the main avd folder, and rename it to config.ini, and then it the avd manager in android studio remove the error "failed to load" and give me the run option.
8. I run the emulator, and it gives the following error:

   `ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.
   Weird, the AVD's config.ini file is malformed. Try re-creating it.`

what I could understand that during the creation of this emulator, it fails to create the config.ini file.
do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you tried with other emulators which are below API level 21

Comment: yes, I tried it with Nexus_5_API_19

Comment: Delete `.android` file, it will be created again and then configure new emulator and try

Comment: See also https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78577 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81552 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81778

Comment: why I cannot find the config.ini file? can you provide a snapshot of the content of this file and I will try to add manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem was resolved once I update android studio to a newer version. I think some bugs were in that version.